# How to make dictionary finderlist with glossaries or index packages?

Tags: xetex, glossaries, indexing

I am making a bilingual Pohnpeian-English dictionary using XeLaTeX and I am trying to find a way to generate an English finderlist. So far I have the Pohnpeian to English section coded like this

`\entry[headword]{headword}{English definition}`

Here are  actual examples

`\entry[kang]{kang}{eat.}
\entry[mwenge]{mwenge}{eat.}
\entry[soai]{soai}{1. tale, story. 2. to tell a tale or bedtime story. See \textbf{soia}.}
\entry[soaia]{soaia}{ to relay, to tell a story. See \textbf{soai}.}`

I have it set for that code to generate a nicely formatted dictionary entry. The English finderlist section is a simplified English to Pohnpeian section with a single English headword followed by all the Pohnpeian words that means that word and their page numbers.

The output for the finderlist that I'm looking for is this:

**eat** kang 30, mwenge 41

**relay** soaia 56

**story** soai 56; **tell a ~** soaia 56

**tale** soai 56

The numbers after each Pohnpeian word would be the page number. If the entries have the same English gloss they are separated by a comma (kang, mwenge). If the entries have a modified  but related headword (tell a ~) they are separated by semicolons. Is there a way to make the finderlist by including some sort of reference in the Pohnpeian-English section like \gls and then automatically generating the finderlist with the above format, similar to the way an index/glossary is generated in LaTeX? The subentry part (as with story) is what I am having particular trouble figuring out.

Comment: If there are more subentries in Pohnpeian language (e.g. kang, mwenge), do you wish to have English sorting or Pohnpeian sorting (a e i o oa u h k l m mw n ng p pw r s d t w)?

Comment: For the Pohnpeian subentries, I want to have Pohnpeian sorting.